# Отступ между картинкой и текстом через 1 div

Tags: css

Нужно сделать отступ между картинкой и текстом, как это будет изображено ниже. Заренее спасибо. Как можно увидеть: там будет 1 div.

P.S. Скриншот - просто пример. Любые совпадения являются случайностью.

Часть исходного кода:

```
<div id="email"><a rel="nofollow"
href="mailto:info@leoparts.com.ua">info@leoparts.com.ua</a></div>
```

Ссылка на скриншот:
http://tau.rghost.ru/58701804/thumb.png

P.S.S. Нужен код сss, как на примере.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#email{
padding-left:5px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/L11dqxwa/

HTML

```
<p class="title">Вариант 1</p>
<div class="email">
    <a rel="nofollow" href="mailto:info@leoparts.com.ua">info@leoparts.com.ua</a>
</div>

<p class="title">Вариант 2</p>
<div class="email2">    
    <a rel="nofollow" href="mailto:info@leoparts.com.ua"><img src="http://www.kofe-varka.com.ua/sites/all/modules/print/icons/mail_icon.gif" alt="" /> info@leoparts.com.ua</a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.title{
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 700;
    margin-top: 50px;
}
.title:first-child{
    margin-top: 0;
}

.email{}
.email a{
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    zoom: 1;
    background:  #2B2B2B url('http://www.kofe-varka.com.ua/sites/all/modules/print/icons/mail_icon.gif') no-repeat 5px center;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 8px 15px 8px 30px;
}
.email a:hover{
    background:  #00f url('http://www.kofe-varka.com.ua/sites/all/modules/print/icons/mail_icon.gif') no-repeat 5px center;
}

.email2{}
.email2 a{
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    zoom: 1;
    background:  #2B2B2B;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 8px 15px 8px 15px;
}
.email2 img{
    vertical-align: middle;  
    padding-right: 5px;
}
.email2 a:hover{
    background:  #c00;
}
```